# Software to communicate between 2 computers on the same LAN

Tags: file-transfer, chat

I have 2 computers on the same LAN and I would like to send messages and exchange files and folders between them.. I dont want to set up a windows workgroup however. I just want to use a tol which will make my life easier. Is there any such tool out ther other than LANchat?

Comment: What OS are you using on the computers?

Comment: Windows 7 on both computers

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=lan+im

Answer (score 1):

For just chatting between machines on the network you can use [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) (Use the Bonjour protocol), or you could try [Miranda IM](http://www.miranda-im.org/) with the [iChat addon](http://addons.miranda-im.org/details.php?action=viewfile&id=1991).

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox, Sugarsync, Google Drive. Otherwise set up FTP. 
In general even if you don't have a workgroup set up, you should be able to access other PCs on the network if they have shared drives.

Comment: How can any of these be used to send messages? Also Dropbox, Sugarsync, Google Drive require internet connections - how would that be applicable to a LAN environment?

Answer (score 0):

If its just sending files between systems, [nitroshare](http://quickmediasolutions.com/apps/14/nitroshare) works pretty well. I run a internal IRC server for messaging, and it might work here as well. Its developed by an Askubuntu regular, and its pretty troublefree

Answer (score 0):

Try [Squiggle](http://squiggle.codeplex.com/). it have a good gui, file transfer is possible